# computing quantiles in R from means

Tags: r, statistics

I have a dataframe:

```
> print(merged)
    AgeGroup    values                ind
1          1 0.2449762 diff_v.ownhigh_avg
2          1 0.2598964 diff_v.ownhigh_avg
3          1 0.2519043 diff_v.ownhigh_avg
4          1 0.2452479 diff_v.ownhigh_avg
5          1 0.2840650 diff_v.ownhigh_avg
6          1 0.2589341 diff_v.ownhigh_avg
7          1 0.3201843 diff_v.ownhigh_avg
8          1 0.3218865 diff_v.ownhigh_avg
9          1 0.2822984 diff_v.ownhigh_avg
10         1 0.3313962 diff_v.ownhigh_avg
```

There are 8 different types of `ind`, and there are 2 `AgeGroup` types.

I am creating a new dataframe that summarises the means and credble intervals based on 2 group factors (AgeGroup and ind).

This is the code that I have:

```
meansCIs <- merged %>%
  group_by(AgeGroup, ind) %>%
  summarise(means = mean(values), .groups = "keep",
          lower_bound = quantile(means,.025),
          upper_bound = quantile(means,.975))
```

This is the output it gives:

```
    # A tibble: 16 x 5
# Groups:   AgeGroup, ind [16]
   AgeGroup ind                  means lower_bound upper_bound
      <dbl> <fct>                <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>
 1        1 diff_v.ownhigh_avg   0.290       0.290       0.290
 2        1 diff_v.ownlow_avg    0.272       0.272       0.272
 3        1 diff_v.otherhigh_avg 0.274       0.274       0.274
 4        1 diff_v.otherlow_avg  0.388       0.388       0.388
 5        1 diff_v.own_avg       0.281       0.281       0.281
```

As you can see, something has gone wrong with computing the credible intervals. It is just replicating the mean for each condition. Does anyone know how I could fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The quantile function is operating on just the single mean value. I think you need to substitute in the “values” variable.

```
merged<- structure(list(AgeGroup = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
                        values = c(0.2449762, 0.2598964, 0.2519043, 0.2452479, 0.284065, 
                                                     0.2589341, 0.3201843, 0.3218865, 0.2822984, 0.3313962), 
                        ind = c("diff_v.ownhigh_avg", "diff_v.ownhigh_avg", "diff_v.ownhigh_avg", "diff_v.ownhigh_avg", 
                                 "diff_v.ownhigh_avg", "diff_v.ownhigh_avg", "diff_v.ownhigh_avg", 
                                 "diff_v.ownhigh_avg", "diff_v.ownhigh_avg", "diff_v.ownhigh_avg" )), 
                   class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))


merged %>%
   group_by(AgeGroup, ind) %>%
   summarise(means = mean(values), .groups = "keep",
             lower_bound = quantile(values,.025),
             upper_bound = quantile(values,.975))

# A tibble: 1 × 5
# Groups:   AgeGroup, ind [1]
     AgeGroup ind                means lower_bound upper_bound
        <int> <chr>              <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>
   1        1 diff_v.ownhigh_avg 0.280       0.245       0.329
```